# plotly visualization not working in Pyspark kernel on EMR Jupyterhub Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, amazon-emr, pyspark

I'm trying to plot graphs using plotly on EMR Jupyterhub Notebook however the graphs are not being rendered in Pyspark kernel. (Note: Python kernel renders the graph just fine)

Sample code I am trying:

```
data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()

I am able to plot a graph with %%display sparkmagic however I am not able to figure out if we can get plotly working with %%display sparkmagic - 

import random
   data = [('Person:%s' % i, i, random.randint(1, 5)) for i in range(1, 50)]
   columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Random']
   spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

%%display
spark_df
```

Has anyone tried this successfully? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the limitation of sparkmagic. You would have to resort to `%%local` magic. From sparkmagic [docs](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic).

> Since all code is run on a remote driver through Livy, all structured data must
> be serialized to JSON and parsed by the Sparkmagic library so that it can be
> manipulated and visualized on the client side. In practice this means that you
> must use Python for client-side data manipulation in %%local mode.